# Exclude every 6th and 7th day from given two dates using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to exclude every 6th and 7th day from two dates and return number of days.

For example start date is 1st sep and end date is 30th sep, then the result should be 4 + 4 = 8 days.

If I take total number of days and divide it by 7 then I can get how many 7th days occur, but for 6th days, this logic is failing.

Problem here is I need to check every 6th and 7th days after 7th day. I mean

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
          x x              x  x                 x  x
```

Any simple logic I am missing here?

Comment: share your code what you have tried so for!

Comment: Do you want to exclude weekends, or?

Comment: No, not only weekends. Every 6th and 7th day whatever the days are. every Monday, Tuesday or every Tuesday, Wednesday etc.. but the gap should be week

Comment: I've updated my answer with a method that just returns the number of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing following simple logic

```
var counter = 1;
    var daysAfterSixSvn = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
         if (counter == 6) {
            counter = counter;              
         }
         else if(counter == 7){
            counter = 0;
         }
         else{
            daysAfterSixSvn = daysAfterSixSvn + 1;
         }
        counter = counter + 1;          
    }
    console.log(daysAfterSixSvn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like:

```
function numberOfDays(days) {
  const c67 = 6/7.;
  var days7 = days / 7.;
  return days - (Math.floor(days7) * 2) - ((days7 - Math.floor(days7)) >= c67 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Then just pass it the total number of days and it will return the number of days without 6th and 7th days.

Logic:

- `c67` simbolises the ratio of 6 / 7, because every 7 days MUST have day 6 also, but we can have 6 days without 7th day
- `days7` calculate the occurance of 7 days (as float) - note the dot
- from the total number of days subtract a total number of 7 day occurrences times 2 (since they also have day 6) `Math.floor(days7) * 2`
- check if the remaining value of the division is equal to the constant, if it is, then the number of days is 6 and we need to subtract another day, if not then the number of days is 5 or less

Hope this helps

Tested values:

```
numberOfDays(5) // 5
numberOfDays(6) // 5
numberOfDays(7) // 5
numberOfDays(8) // 6
numberOfDays(20) // 15
numberOfDays(21) // 15
numberOfDays(22) // 16
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ye21m683/  Fiddle example

Comment: this will not for 6th days, as I need to calculate 6th day again starting after 7th day

Comment: What do you mean by, `I need to calculate 6th day again starting after 7th day` your question is not clear. This code does exactly what you described in your question, remove all 6th and 7th days.

Comment: As u can see in my question, I marked 6,7 and 13, 14. I calculated 6th day starting from 7. In ur case every 6th day counts 6, 12, 18.... In my case I need to calculate 6, 13, 20..

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, copy the function in the console and try it like that while I make a fiddle.

Comment: if I pass 27 the answer should be 20 but returning 21

Comment: Yes I missclicked and `==` instead of `>=` now it's fine, reload the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple logic:

```
var start = 1, end = 31, current = 0;
while(current <=end){
   var next = current + 6, next1 = next+1;

   //If you want to print other then 6th and 7th
   for(var i = current +1; i< next && i <=end; i++)
       console.log(i);

   /*if(next <= end)
      console.log(next); //Or do what you want with this.
   if(next1 <= end)
      console.log(next1); //Or do what you want with this.*/
   current = next1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. My answer will leave out each 6th and 7th day of any given date range.

All days will be added to the result array, except for the 6n-th and 7n-th. The rejected days will be logged to the console so you can better see which days are rejected by the method.

```js
const
  millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  
function createArrayWithDays(start, end) {
  const
    result = [],
    // Calculate the diference between the start and end.
    dateDifference = end.getTime() - start.getTime(),
    // Convert the milliseconds back to days and add 1 to make the end date inclusive of the range.
    days = (dateDifference / millisecondsPerDay) + 1;
    
  let
    currentDate = new Date(start);
    
  // Iterate over the number of days in the range.
  for (let day=1; day <= days; day++) {
    // When the current index can be divided by 6 or 7 the modulo is 0 and the day should be in the result array.
    if (
      day % 6 !== 0 &&
      day % 7 !== 0
    ) {
      result.push(currentDate.getDate());
    } else {
      console.log(`Reject ${currentDate.toDateString()} it is the 6n-th or 7n-th day of the range.`);
    }
    
    // Continue to the next date;
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  
  return result;

}


console.log('Days for September');
console.log(createArrayWithDays(new Date(2017, 8, 1), new Date(2017, 8, 30)));

console.log('Days for mid Sept to mid Oct');
console.log(createArrayWithDays(new Date(2017, 8, 15), new Date(2017, 9, 15)));
```

If you just want the total number, you could do this:

```js
const
  millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function numberOfDays(start, end) {
  const
    result = [],
    // Calculate the diference between the start and end.
    dateDifference = end.getTime() - start.getTime(),
    // Convert the milliseconds back to days and add 1 to make the 
    // end date inclusive of the range.
    days = (dateDifference / millisecondsPerDay) + 1,
    // Calculate the number of days that don't make up a full week 
    // but this should never be more than 5.
    rest = Math.min(5, days % 7),
    // Calculate the number of full weeks in the range
    weeks = Math.floor(days/7);

  // For each week, leave out 2 days and add the rest.
  return (weeks * 5) + rest;
}


console.log('Days for September');
console.log(numberOfDays(new Date(2017, 8, 1), new Date(2017, 8, 30)));

console.log('Days for mid Sept to mid Oct');
console.log(numberOfDays(new Date(2017, 8, 15), new Date(2017, 9, 15)));

console.log('Days when a range of 6 days');
console.log(numberOfDays(new Date(2017, 8, 1), new Date(2017, 8, 6)));
```